# Combinatorial description of a 120-cell

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry

I'd like a combinatorial description of the 1-skeleton of the 120-cell (roughly) along the lines of the following description of the 1-skeleton of a dodecahedron.

(View all elements of product sets as cyclically ordered words.)

Vertex set: the $8$ words in $\{0,1\}^3$ ; $12$ more words in $\{0,1,X\}^3$ that have just a single $X$.

Edge set: $24$ edges represented by words of $\{0,1,\hat{0},\hat{1}\}^3$ where exactly one component wears a hat; $6$ more edges represented by those linear orders of $\{0, X, \hat{X} \}$ or  $\{1, X, \hat{X} \}$ where $\hat{X}$ occurs (cyclically) just right of  $X$.

Vertices adjacent to an edge arise either by specializing 
$\hat{X}$ to $0$ or $1$; 
$\hat{0}$ to $0$ or $X$; or
$\hat{1}$ to $1$ or $X$.

Comment: One can represent faces of the dodecahedron as cyclic words containing two numbers, one hatted, one not, and an $\hat{X}$; the $\hat{X}$ must sit cyclically to the right of the hatted number.  For the edges on a face, either: specialize the $\hat{X}$ to $0$ or $1$; remove the hat from the hatted number and specialize $\hat{X}$ to $\hat{0}$ or $\hat{1}$; or replace the hatted number by $X$.  For the vertices on a face, either remove the hat from the hatted number and replace $\hat{X}$ by $0$, $1$ or $X$; or replace the hatted number by $X$ and $\hat{X}$ by $0$ or $1$.

Comment: What's the largest symmetric group that embeds into the symmetry group of the 120-cell?

Comment: @Will Sawin http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0510191

Comment: This description sounds like what one would get from describing representatives for the cosets of the parabolic subgroup corresponding to an endpoint in the Coxeter diagram for the Coxeter group of the dodehedron. Maybe you can do something similar for the other group?

Comment: Your description of the vertices of the dodecahedron is just a disguised version of their Cartesian coordinates. The eight words in $\{+,-\}$ are the points $(+1,+1,+1)$, $(+1,+1,-1), \ldots \in \mathbb R^3$. The twelve words in  $\{+,-,0\}$ with just a single $0$ are the points $(\phi,\phi^{-1},0)$, $(\phi,-\phi^{-1},0)$, $(-\phi,\phi^{-1},0)$, $(-\phi,-\phi^{-1},0)$, $(0,\phi,\phi^{-1})$, ... ($\phi$ is the golden ratio, and the cyclic order between the symbols '$\phi$', '$\phi^{-1}$', and '$0$' should be respected). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedron#Cartesian_coordinates

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how similar you want the constructions to be. But here is a reason why you shouldn't expect it: You can use this description of the 1-skeleton of the dodecahedron to build an isometric embedding of the graph as a metric space (path distance as a metric) into $\mathbb R^{10}$ with the $l_1$ metric by encoding $X$ and the edges as appropriate sequences of bits.

Ultimately you can't construct the 1-skeleton of the 120-cell using such a $\{0,1,*\}$ encoding because [the skeleton of the 120-cell is not $l_1$ emebeddable](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X96001690).